# Atom "find in project" doesn't return results in Buildroot's output/build directory

Tags: atom-editor, buildroot

Atom's "find in project" fails to return results in Buildroot's output/build directory and subdirectories.
Is there anything I can do or change in atom's setup to make it work ?

**Steps to Reproduce**

```
git clone git://git.busybox.net/buildroot; cd buildroot
make qemu_aarch64_virt_defconfig
make host-pkgconf
cd output/build; atom .
ctl-shift-f
Search for something common like char
Nothing is returned
grep -r char returns plenty
```

The same problem persists when using atom in the output/build/* directories individually.

**Expected behavior**

To be able to "find in project" in the subdirectories of buildroot's output/build directory.

**Actual behavior**

No results are returned despite grep -r in the same directory finding plenty.

This problem is also posed on the [atom github page](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/23724)

Comment: Is `output` or `output/build` in your `.gitignore`?

Comment: yes - output is in the .gitignore. That must be it. Unfortunately output has to remain in the .gitignore file. Whats an idea for solving that problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, *"Find in project"* ignores files that are ignored by your Version Control System. This settin can be disabled in the Core Settings.

[image]

Since this is not ideal for most workflows, you might want to look at third-party packages that such as [`atom-ignore`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ignore) or [similar packages](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=atom-ignore&commit=Search).